# Trying to use writeFileSync in conjunction with Node Exec to programmatically run tests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create an editor like FreecodeCamp and I ran into an interesting problem. I have my frontend sending a string that I then try to convert into a file using the node process `writeFileSync`. I then try to call a script programmatically using exec from the child_processes module.

```
    const str = req.body.code.replace(/"/g, "");
   await fs.writeFileSync('./test/add.js', str)
    await exec('npm run test', (error, stdOut) => {
        console.log('error', error);
        console.log('stdout', stdOut)
        res.json({ message: stdOut })
    })
    

})
```

If I commit out `await fs.writeFileSync('./test/add.js', str)` it works perfectly. How can I write a file and then run my script?

Comment: There's no need to `await` either a Sync call or `await` a callback function. These are mutually exclusive. That said, this seems like this should work even with the unnecesssary `await`s. What error or problematic behavior do you get? Or, if it works perfectly, I guess you're done, right?

Comment: @ggorlen the problem is it doesn't run the ``` exec```  when I use ```writeFileSync``` . Now if I omit the writeFileSync method it works perfectly. I get no errors. Maybe I should try to wrap it in a try catch